# Make table with two new columns that categorize another column by even or odd and that sums all even and odd numbers in a category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure of table:

| category | user_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.01 |
| A | 2 | 0.05 |
| A | 3 | 0.09 |
| A | 4 | 0.12 |
| B | 1 | 0.34 |
| B | 2 | 0.27 |
| B | 3 | 0.08 |
| B | 4 | 0.12 |

There are many more rows in the actual table. This is just an example.

**I want to make a table that keeps 'category', makes another column 'user_id_type' that labels even and odd, and another new column (value_sum) that sums all of the 'value' based on 'category' and 'user_id_type'.**

So, it will have only four rows, with 'A' 'odd' and the sum, 'A' 'even' and the sum, 'B' 'odd' and the sum, 'B' 'even' and the sum.

**I want it to look like this:**

| category | user_id_type | value_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | odd | 0.10 |
| A | even | 0.17 |
| B | odd | 0.42 |
| B | even | 0.39 |

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `category` VARCHAR(2),
  `user_id` INT(2), 
  `value` DECIMAL(3,2)
 );
INSERT INTO table_1
(`category`, `user_id`, `value`)
VALUES
('A', 1, 0.01),
('A', 2, 0.05),
('A', 3, 0.09),
('A', 4, 0.12),
('B', 1, 0.34),
('B', 2, 0.27),
('B', 3, 0.08),
('B', 4, 0.12)
;
```

Comment: Thank you all so much! I wish I could give the checkmark to multiple answers, since they all worked. I gave the checkmark to the user that made the new table and then a CASE WHEN, because that's how I was trying to do it, but the syntax was wrong. Thank you to the users that showed me MOD CASE. You're helping me learn a ton!

Comment: Thank you for your very good description and your kind words!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table according to your requirements and fill this table using a select like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_2
SELECT category, 
CASE WHEN user_id % 2 = 0 THEN 'even' ELSE 'odd' END user_id_type, 
SUM(value) FROM table_1 GROUP BY user_id_type, category ORDER BY category;
```

Please have a look here to see it's working: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=f80291f141f1e12350a1832f330df3f0)

Comment: this uses the  wrong sort check the result

Comment: A specific sorting was not requested. I'm sure the author of this question is able to change the sorting if intended. As example, just change the order by to ORDER BY category, user_id_type DESC and it will be sorted the other way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MOD` with a `case` expression to determine odd or even, and then use the results as a derived table to aggregate from:

```
select a.category
  , a.user_id_type
  , sum(a.value)
from
(
  SELECT t.category
    , case
        when MOD(t.user_id, 2) = 0 then 'Even'
        else 'Odd'
      end user_id_type
    , t.value
  FROM tbl t
) a
group by a.category, a.user_id_type
;
```

**Edit: Adding Lemon's recommendation for compactness**

Here is the example with Lemon's compacted version:

```
select category
  , user_id_type
  , sum(value)
from
(
  SELECT category
    , IF(MOD(t.user_id, 2)=0, 'even', 'odd') user_id_type
    , value
  FROM tbl t
) a
group by a.category, a.user_id_type
;
```

Comment: instead of `CASE`, you can make it more compact with `IF(MOD(t.usr_id, 2)=0, 'even', 'odd')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use MODulo to dete4rmin the odds

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_1 (
>   `category` VARCHAR(2),
>   `user_id` INT(2), 
>   `value` DECIMAL(3,2)
>  );
> INSERT INTO table_1
> (`category`, `user_id`, `value`)
> VALUES
> ('A', 1, 0.01),
> ('A', 2, 0.05),
> ('A', 3, 0.09),
> ('A', 4, 0.12),
> ('B', 1, 0.34),
> ('B', 2, 0.27),
> ('B', 3, 0.08),
> ('B', 4, 0.12)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `category`
> , MAX(CASE WHEN  MOD( `user_id`,2) = 1 then 'Even' ELSE 'Odd' ENd ) odds, SUM(`value`) 
> FROM table_1
> GROUP BY category, MOD( `user_id`,2)
> ORDER BY category, MOD( `user_id`,2) ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> category | odds | SUM(`value`)
> :------- | :--- | -----------:
> A        | Odd  |         0.17
> A        | Even |         0.10
> B        | Odd  |         0.39
> B        | Even |         0.42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c78f69f773e7a7d2fad97b72d22c1be3)*